# Show that a random variable X is geometric distributed

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable. (values in $\mathbb{N}$ )

I already show: X is geometric distributed $\rightarrow$ $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$ $k$ + $j$ | $X$ $\ge$ $k$ ) $=$ $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$ $j$ ) .

But I need help with:

$X$ is geometric distributed if $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$ $k$ + $j$ | $X$ $\ge$ $k$ ) $=$ $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$ $j$ ) , $j$,$k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N_0}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923009/memoryless-property-and-geometric-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you start by noting that:
\begin{align}
P(X\geq 1) = P(X\geq k+1|X\geq k ) = \frac{P(X\geq k+1)}{P(X\geq k)}
\end{align}
This is a recurrence equation. Define $p_j:=P(X\geq j)$, so our recurrence relation is:
\begin{align}
p_1 p_{k} = p_{k+1}
\end{align} 
Can you solve this? After solving it put everything together to get an expression for $P(X=k)$ and conclude that it has the form of an geometric mass function. Let me know if this hint is not enough.

Comment: Sorry I have to delete my comment. Something wrong edited and couln't change it anymore. Hm we know that $(p_1)^k$ is equal to $p_k$. Is this helpful?

Comment: @Mugumble Yes. Now you know $P(X\geq k) =p_1^k$ for $k\geq 0$. You also know that $P(X=k) = P(X\geq k) - P(X\geq k+1) $. So $P(X=k)=....$? Can you finish?

Comment: I could say that: $P$( $X$ = $k$ ) = $(p_1)^k$ * (1 - $p_1$). Then we could use the fact that $p_1$ = $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$ 1 ) = 1 - $P$ ( $X$ = 0 ). We get $P$ ( $X$ = $k$ ) = ( 1 - $P$ ( $X$ = 0 ))^k * ( $P$ ($X$ = 0) ). Am I right or where is my mistake?

Comment: @Mugumble Yes. Although I think that you could stop after the first expression for $P(X=k) $, since then you already see that it is the probability mass function of a geometric distribution with parameter $p_1$.

Comment: One last remark: I think you made a little mistake in the first line of your answer. You mean $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$  k +1 | $X$ $\ge$ k ) not $P$ ( $X$ $\ge$  k +1 | $X$ $\ge$ 1), right?

Comment: @Mugumble Yes! Ill edit in a minute