# Geometric Distribution - Memoryless property - geometric series

Tags: probability-distributions, geometric-series

I came across this post here and can't comprehend one of the steps here. [Memoryless property and geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923009/memoryless-property-and-geometric-distribution/3452494#3452494).

Can someone please explain to me how you can go from this

$$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^{i-1}p-\sum_{i=0}^{s-1}(1-p)^{i-1}p$$
to this $$=\frac{p}{1-p}(\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}-\frac{1-(1-p)^s}{1-(1-p)})$$? I understand pretty much everything on this exercise except where the factor p/1-p comes from. So geometric series for finite sequence being the second element and geometric series for infinte sequence being the first one. However wouldn't you just write $={p}*\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$?? Why $\frac{p}{1-p}$??

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] tag. Please read the tag summary when using a tag.

Comment: The sums should start at $i=1$, not $i=0$. Also, there is no need to write the sum from $i=s$ to $\infty$ as the difference of those two sums; we can compute directly
$$
\sum_{i=s}^\infty (1-p)^{i-1}p = \frac p{1-p}\sum_{i=s}^\infty (1-p)^i=\frac p{1-p}\cdot \frac{(1-p)^s}p = (1-p)^{s-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please explain it more, how/where you get the factor p/1-p?